# how to keep the thumbnail inline so that it is in one line with buttons to move from one to another

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I obtained the code from online.
The thumbnail is below the image slider. 
Here is the html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">

    <div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     <!-- main slider carousel items -->
     <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
<img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
         </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480/888/FFF" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
                      </div>
     <!--and so on-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
     <!-- main slider carousel nav controls --> 
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-      slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!--/main slider carousel-->

<!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->
</div>
<div class="row">

      <ul class="list-inline"  >
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-1">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-2">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
      <li> <a id="carousel-selector-3">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
            <li> <a id="carousel-selector-4">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
<!-- and so on -->

           <li> <a id="carousel-selector-12">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-responsive">
      </a></li>
        </ul>


</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
 var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
 var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
 id = parseInt(id);
 $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
});

// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slide', function (e) {
 var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
 id = parseInt(id);
 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
 $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
 });
 })
```

The thumbnail is inline at the bottom but it takes more than oneline. I want it to be in one line with buttons to move back and forth. How can I keep it in one line? Can anyone help me with the code for this?

Comment: its already inline and click the first 3  thumb working?  where did you find the code ?

Comment: Its inline but if there are more images it takes more than one line. I want it  to be in only one line with buttons so that the extra images are hidden and can be controlled by buttons.

here is the link  http://www.bootply.com/dIeM1rMmin

Comment: do you want to inline them or just remove the thumb section ?

Comment: I want them inline. (Something like lightSlider bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html code you have some extra div and jQuery the last line '})'  is extra and you need to add thumb section how many slider you have add in the main slider .. and this class in  thumb section will hide in small device "col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" And try to understand how bootstrap work in responsive [#responsive-utilities-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) ..  [live fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0yskk4uk/4/)

```js
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
   });

 $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function() {
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
  var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length - 1);
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
// when the carousel slides, auto update
$('#myCarousel').on('slide', function(e) {
  var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
  $('[id=carousel-selector-' + id + ']').addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
      ul.list-inline
       {
      display: inline-flex;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" > 

 </script>

   <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12" id="slider">

        <div class="col-md-12" id="carousel-bounding-box">
         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
          <!-- main slider carousel items -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=one" 
           class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=two" 
             class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=three" class="img-
      responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=four" 
        class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=five"
         class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=six"
         class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=seven"
      class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480&amp;text=eight"
            class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <!--and so on-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- main slider carousel nav controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" 
        data- slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true">    
        </span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" 
         data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria- 
           hidden="true">
        </span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!--/main slider carousel-->

  <!-- thumb navigation carousel items -->

  <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">

    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-0" class="selected">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=one" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-1">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=two" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-2">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=three" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=four" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=five" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-5">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=six" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=seven" class="img-
       responsive">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a id="carousel-selector-7">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60&amp;text=eight" class="img-
        responsive">
        </a>
      </li>

      <!-- and so on -->
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the jquery is not working for the 11th and 12th thumbnail images. If I click image no 11 it shows image no 1. jsfiddle.net/0yskk4uk/9 

And if there are too many images the bottom thumbnail looks messy. Is there any code to  create a navigation/slider such that only a fixed amount of thumbnail images will be at the bottom and it can be scrolled to get excess to further images?

Comment: i already update the code don't you read the top ? and the live updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0yskk4uk/4/ its already hidden in small device

Comment: Yes I have read that. I was taking about the jquery code.  It works fine upto 10 images. 
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/0yskk4uk/9/). In the link please see  the 11th and 12th  image in the thumbnail.  If I click image no 11 it shows image no 1 instead of image no. 11.

Comment: so this is the problem in javascript .length-1 
but still I won't fix it with script alternately u can use  [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/0yskk4uk/11/ ]  this just nothing change the thumb <a data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"> like this 
and if you want to hide the thumb on mobile add   <div class="col-md-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs"> this and remove the <div class="row"> which hold the thumb section . hope you have understand what i'm saying